# How to make component re-render when value from outside changes?

Tags: javascript, authentication, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

So, I have simple code (class) like this:

```
export default class LoginAction {
  isLoggedIn = () => {
    return true
  }
}
```

And I used it in my other classes like this:

```
export default class Main extends Component {
  render = () => {
    const loginAction = new LoginAction()

    if (loginAction.isLoggedIn()) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Header headerText={'Post List'} />
          <PostList />
        </View>
      )
    }

    ....... (split)
  }
}
```

The question is, when I change the return value on the isLoggedIn function, why Main component not re-rendered?

It's React Native, and I use Hot Reloading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A component re-renders only in 2 situations:

- if its `state` has changed
- if the received `props` have changed

In your `Main` component, none of these situations happen.

To fix it, you could pass `isLoggedIn` to your component:

```
// index.js

const loginAction = new LoginAction()
let isLoggedIn = loginAction.isLoggedIn()

const setLoggedUser = user => {
  loginAction.setLoggedUser(user)
  isLoggedIn = true
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    {!isLoggedIn && <Login setLoggedUser={setLoggedUser} />}
    <Main isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

And use this prop in your component's render:

```
export default class Main extends Component {
  render = () => {
    if (this.props.isLoggedIn) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Header headerText={'Post List'} />
          <PostList />
        </View>
      )
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

In doing so, your component will re-render when `isLoggedIn` changes.

Comment: Or `.forceUpdate()` I think. Maybe there are others too?

Comment: @GG. Woho, I have read a little bit about it. But, what I try to figure it out is when I make the function on the other class. Is it possible?

Comment: @naomik wow I didn't know about this method. :) As a side note, from the doc: "Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from this.props and this.state in render()."

Comment: @naomik Hmm, I don't think so. I've found so many answers that say don't use forceUpdate().

Comment: @GG., yeah it's only meant to be used in special circumstances ^_^

Comment: @nabilftd i only mention it because of the way GG's answer was worded: "a component re-renders only in 2 situations" – it's actually more if you include `.forceUpdate`. It was meant to help make the list exhaustive, not to encourage you to use it in your situation.

Comment: @naomik Whoops, I don't get it before, sorry :D

Comment: @nabilftd Actually, I'm not sure you need to have `isLoggedIn()` in a class. To be sure about it, I would need more code to see the relation between `LoginAction` and the rest of your app. Some questions: How does `isLoggedIn()` change from `false` to `true`? Do you have a component `Login`?

Comment: @GG. Of course, I'll make it. But for this time, I just try like that. Further, the LoginAction will contain OAuth2 flow.

Comment: @GG. So what I expect, when I call `isLoggedIn`, It would check a key in the localStorage. If exist, true and vice versa. I just want to make sure my code well organized (if possible).

Comment: @nabilftd I updated a bit my answer. :) Can't really do more without knowing exactly how you are going to handle the authentication on your app. ;)

Comment: @GG. Thank you, I'll try it. I'm sorry, because at this time, I only have something like that.

Comment: @GG. I think I got some idea from your code. So, I must change the `isLoggedIn` value when rendering the Main component? What I think before, I could make a change to `isLoggedIn` value inside `LoginAction` as well.

Comment: @nabilftd `loginAction.isLoggedIn()` should return a computed value, like `isLoggedIn = () => this.loggedUser !== null`. And you should have a setter like `loginAction.setLoggedUser = user => this.loggedUser = user`.